# Как изменить ширину SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android

Использую библиотеку [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) для создания выплывающего меню.
Понятно, как сделать, чтобы оно открывалось не на весь экран по вертикали. А как сделать, чтобы с боков тоже были отступы и было видно часть основной активности?

Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`margin` и выставление ширины не помогают.

Разметка:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight=".25"
 android:gravity="top"
 sothree:umanoPanelHeight="?android:actionBarSize"
 sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/paraText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<include
    layout="@layout/pers_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".75"/>
```

pers_menu.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  ...
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="57dp"/>
```

Может у кого есть опыт? Или может сейчас используется какая-то более прогрессивная библиотека?

Comment: Разметку покажите

Answer (score 1):

Положите Вашу разметку в родительский `LinearLayout`, у него выставьте атрибут android:gravity="center_horizontal". И у `SlidingUpPanelLayout` попробуйте выставить вес `android:layout_weight=".7"`, к примеру

Comment: не помогает. Поигрался с гравитацией, шириной и весами, результат тот же - края он вообще не воспринимает и оставляет их белыми/непрозрачными.